# Formula based on first monday or tuesday etc of the week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to put a year into a cell (say A1), then the day of the week you want (say Monday in cell A2) and enter into the 12 cells below it the first monday of each month (or first tuesday, etc, based on whats in cell A2)?

I have been able to figure out how to do it with 1 day but I would like it to be interactive.

```
=DATE(2022,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12},7-WEEKDAY(DATE(2022,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12},1)-5,3))
```

Comment: Could you explain with data? Also, what have you tried? Look I to `WEEKDAY()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Office 365:

```
=LET(yr,A1,
    wkdy,MATCH(PROPER(A2),{"Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday","Sunday"},0),
    mnt,SEQUENCE(12),
    DATE(yr,mnt,1)+MOD(8-WEEKDAY(DATE(yr,mnt,1),10+wkdy),7))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats perfect, thank you! I couldn't figure out the coding but after reading yours it make 1000% more sense.

Comment: Can I impose on you once further? What if I wanted to just put in a date (rather than a year) and get the next 12. Is that possible?

Comment: That is a new question and should get a new post.

Answer (score 0):

You where pretty close with your formula

```
=DATE(A1,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12},7)-WEEKDAY(DATE(A1,{1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10;11;12},7),A2)
```

Where
`A1` = year string
`A2` = day of the week as number (1 = Saturday, 2 = Sunday, etc.)